# integrate 2D gaussian in python

Tags: python, integration, gaussian

I've defined a 2D gaussian like this:

```
def gauss2D((x, y), A, x0, y0, sx, sy, offset):
    g = offset + A*np.exp(-((x - x0) ** 2. / (2. * sx ** 2) + (y - y0) ** 2 / (2. * sy ** 2)))
    return g.ravel()
```

and I would to integrate it between +/-sx and +/-sy. I know all parameters from a previous fit of my data : `popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(gauss2D, (x, y), src_region.ravel(), p0=initial_guess)`

Can I use `dbquad` ? Or I need to use Gauss-Hermite quadratures ?

I've already tried `dbquad` but returns :

```
flux_fit = dblquad(gauss2D, -popt[3], popt[3], lambda x: -popt[4], lambda x: popt[4],
                                         args=(popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4], popt[5]))

return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: gauss2D() takes exactly 7 arguments (8 given)
```

Thanks